# stdout output is not saved to list when I execute command with paramiko

Tags: python, stdout, paramiko

Before the code below, I make a ssh connection to a server and I try to get some output. Here is the code:

```
a = [('one','oneFC'),('two','twoH')]
b = [None] * len(a)
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    command = r"ls /home/aaa/ | grep " + item[0] #I need one and two here
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read()
    b[i] = stdout.read()
    print b[i]
```

When I print the output (with stdout.print()) it looks good, but when I print b[i], the variable is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already read everything after `print stdout.read()`. You should omit the first  print statement and directly assign to `b[i]`.

```
a = [('one','oneFC'),('two','twoH')]
b = [None] * len(a)
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    command = r"ls /home/aaa/ | grep " + item[0] #I need one and two here
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    b[i] = stdout.read()
    print b[i]
```

Comment: Thank you, I would not have imagined that a print would "empty" the stdout.